# How do we pass String[] args in java

Tags: java, intellij-idea

New to Java, coming from Python here.

How do we pass `String[] args` in console. I'm trying to execute the following password generator code (retrieved from: [RC](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Password_generator#Java))

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num, len;

    try {
        if (args.length != 2)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();

            len = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            if (len < 4 || len > 16) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
            num = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            if (num < 1 || num > 10) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
            for (String pw : generatePasswords(num, len)) {
                System.out.println(pw);
            }
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println("Provide the length of the passwords (min 4, max 16) you "
                    + "want to generate,\n and how many (min 1, max 10)");
            String s = console.next();
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Since the `args[]` is an array, I have tried: {5, 5}, {"5","5"},[5,5]. Nothing seems to be working.

Any advise is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `args` doesn't come from the console. It holds command-line arguments.

Comment: `String s = console.next();` - where is console defined in your code?

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass the arguments along with the execution command, on the console

```
java -cp . App arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using intellij then go to `Run > Edit Configurations` menu setting. A dialog box will appear. Now you can add arguments to the `Program arguments` input field.

Otherwise you can pass the arguments via command line when you run the program.

```
java App arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't put commas after each argument.

Comment: Sorry My bad. Edited my answer